# Multiple SPF records may cause delivery and spam classification issues Route53 and G-Suite

Tags: amazon-route53, google-workspace, spf, mx-record

Using G-suite email and DNS configuration for MX records in Route53, I'm blocked on how I can solve this error:

> Multiple SPF records may cause delivery and spam classification
>   issues. v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all v=spf1
>   include:transmail.net ~all

Route53 only allow a single TXT record for SPF information. Route53 does allow you to use new lines for additional SFP information.

However, when running the [G-Suite check](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/checkmx/check), I get the error quoted above and some clients are seeing our emails as SPAM.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: I was unable to FIX this in Route53, so I used Cloudflare as my DNS which allows multiple TXT records entries.

Answer (score 4):

You should have one SPF record for your domain, but you can have multiple `include` directives in the SPF record.  You might want to try something like this:

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com include:transmail.net ~all
```

Comment: Struggling to get this to work as suggested, I entered:  "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com include: google-site-verification=xyz include:transmail.net ~all"

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to fix this was to proxy the DNS records in Cloudflare which allows an SPF record per line.

Answer (score 0):

A domain MUST NOT have multiple SPF records, SPF fails with PermError otherwise.

An SPF record is a TXT record in the DNS starting exactly with "v=spf1", followed by an array of mechanisms and/or modifiers.

An SPF check starts by fetching all TXT records starting exactly with "v=spf1" on a domain:

- if no such record is found, it returns None;
- if multiple such records are found, it returns PermError.

If you have multiple services to add to SPF, you would need to combine them like  mti2935.

Learn more here: https://dmarcly.com/blog/can-i-have-multiple-spf-records-on-my-domain

Comment: Cloudflare allows multiple, maybe they are transforming multi records this into a single record in the background